# Why does dict(k=4, z=2).update(dict(l=1)) return None in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Why does `dict(k=4, z=2).update(dict(l=1))` return `None`? It seems as if it should return `dict(k=4, z=2, l=1)`? I'm using Python 2.7 should that matter.

Comment: Why are people voting this down? to me it was very beneficial.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452995/why-doesnt-a-python-dict-update-return-the-object

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `.update()` method alters the dictionary *in place* and returns `None`. The dictionary *itself* is altered, no altered dictionary needs to be returned.

Assign the dictionary first:

```
a_dict = dict(k=4, z=2)
a_dict.update(dict(l=1))
print a_dict
```

This is clearly documented, see the [`dict.update()` method documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys. Return `None`.

Comment: What do you mean by "in place"?

Comment: @raster-blaster: The method alters the dictionary it operates on. It does not return the altered dictionary.

Comment: Oh shoot, I see. Seems rather obvious now. Thank you very much. As a sidenote, I think you meant a_dict instead of dict on the second line.

Comment: Tried doing that, it's telling me to wait 7 minutes, will do it asap.

Answer (score 3):

[`dict.update()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method does update in place. It does not return the modified dict, but `None`.

The doc says it in first line:

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys. **Return None.**

Answer (score 3):

For completion's sake, if you do want to return a modified version of the dictionary, without modifying the original you can do it like this:

```
original_dict = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
new_dict = dict(original_dict.items() + {'c': 'f', 'g': 'h'}.items())
```

Which gives you the following:

```
new_dict == {'a': 'b', 'c': 'f', 'g': 'h'}
original_dict == {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```