# Why do I get a TypeError when building a dict()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of dicts from which I need to extract, into a new list, some elements. It works fine for one element:

```
d = [
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": {
            "x": 3
        },
        "blah": 4
    },
    {
        "a": 10,
        "b": {
            "x": 30
        },
        "blah": 40
    },
]

z = [k["b"] for k in d]
print(z)
```

This outputs `[{'x': 3}, {'x': 30}]` which is the extracted data.

I now realize that I also need to include in the extracted dict another element from the original one: `a` (and its value).

I thought I would just take the value if `b` and `update()` it with a pair:

```
y = [k["b"].update({"a": k["a"]}) for k in d]
print(y)
```

This will not work (returns `[None, None]`) as `update()` does not return the resulting dict. A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453013/903011) led me to build a `dict()` from the components:

```
x = [dict(a=k["a"], **k["b"]) for k in d]
print(x)
```

This crashes with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/config/scratches/scratch_21.py", line 24, in <module>
    x = [dict(a=k["a"], **k["b"]) for k in d]
  File "C:/dev/config/scratches/scratch_21.py", line 24, in <listcomp>
    x = [dict(a=k["a"], **k["b"]) for k in d]
TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

**What does that mean? Specifically: what are the "multiple values" when there is only one for that key (an integer) ?**

Comment: After you add the data ... what do you want each entry in the final list to look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing in multiple `a` keys to the `dict()` call; one as a keyword argument, the other in the `**` expanded mapping:

```
>>> dict(a=41, **{'a': 82})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

It doesn't really matter what object you are calling here, keyword arguments must be unique in any call.

You presumably are using the same dictionaries you called `.update()` on, so now all your `k['b']` dictionaries have an `a` key as well. Re-build your `d` list and your code will work:

```
>>> [k["b"] for k in d]
[{'x': 3}, {'x': 30}]
>>> [dict(a=k["a"], **k["b"]) for k in d]
[{'a': 1, 'x': 3}, {'a': 10, 'x': 30}]
```

Comment: Ahhh, I understand. The successive trials have modified `k['b']` - it is true that I was testing all the above code one after the other. Indeed, commenting out the intermediates and leaving only the last one fixed the problem. Thanks!