# Class property that contains a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, properties

Could you please explain, why `v2` doesn't contain `{"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}` and `v3` does?

```
class MyClass:

    def foo(self):

        v1 = self.d.get('A')
        print(v1)
        # 1

        v2 = self.d.update({"C": 3})
        print(v2)
        # None

        v3 = self.d
        v3.update({"C": 3})
        print(v3)
        # {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}

    @property
    def d(self):
        return {"A": 1, "B": 2}

mc = MyClass()
mc.foo()
```

Comment: `dict.update` is an *in-place* operation, it doesn't return anything (well, it returns `None`). If you just `print(self.d)` *before* creating `v3` you'll see `self.d["C"]` is already `3`. Canonical duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452995/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for the reply! I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.d.update({"C": 3})` is a void function. It returns a `None` value. In your case, `v2` is being re-assigned to `None`.