# How to add element to dict in list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to construct a list containing some dict using **list comprehensions**. I tried to use `.update()` but get `None`.

For examples

```
  >>> data = [ {}.update({'demo': i}) for i in range(5) } ]
  >>> data
  [None, None, None, None, None]
```

While what I want is:

```
  [ {'demo': 0}, {'demo': 1}, {'demo': 2}, {'demo': 3}, {'demo': 4}]
```

Any idea? thx.

As for **coldspeed's confusion**, the example above is just a simple demo, what if `{}` is not an empty directory but arbitrary directory? If we just need to update each item which is dict in a list using list comprehensions, I think maybe we can't avoid `update`. That's why I came up with `.update()`.

Sorry for my poor information in the first time.

Comment: What's wrong with `[{'demo': i} for i in range(5) } ]`? update is an in-place operation, so it returns None and updates the dictionary in-place, before its reference is lost and it is garbage collected.

Comment: How did you come up with `.update`? o_0

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452995/why-doesnt-a-python-dict-update-return-the-object

Comment: `[{'demo':i} for i in range(5)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [coldspeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/coldspeed) said in a comment to your question:

> What's wrong with `[{'demo': i} for i in range(5) } ]?`

The problem with the code you have shown is:

> `update` is an in-place operation, so it returns None and updates the dictionary in-place, before its reference is lost and it is garbage collected.

However, let us give you the benefit of the doubt, and assume that your *actual* problem is a little bit more complicated.  The solution is to define a small function:

```
def f(i):
    result = {}
    result.update({'demo': i})
    return result

data = [ f(i) for i in range(5) } ]
```

Obviously, you would only do this if you have an actual need for the additional complexity.

Comment: Thx, it is helpful. I can use a function wrapper to return a new dict object in the list comprehensions to solve the problem while I wonder whether there's any briefer solution.  I will accept your answer if there are no more briefer solution. Thx once more.