# Python: can I use dict update inside the map function?

Tags: python

I've got the following input `inp = [{1:100}, {3:200}, {8:300}]` and I would like to convert it to the dictionary. I can do

```
dct = dict()  
for a in inp:  
    dct.update(a)
```

or I can do

```
_ = [dct.update(a) for a in inp]
```

But I would like to do something like:

```
map(dct.update, inp)
```

Comment: `map` operation is to transform a result and retrieve it so no. Like your uss of list comprehension which is to retieve result and not use statefull methods

Comment: You *can* but you *shouldn't*.  And the same applies to your list comprehension, you *shouldn't* be using it to call `dict.update`. Both `map` and comprehension constructs are functional programming constructs to express mapping/filtering operations on arbitrary iterables using pure-functions. Your functions shouldn't have side-effects, and they definitely shouldn't be used only for side-effects

Comment: You should not be ideally doing a list comprehension also for this task. Your first approach seems easy and probably the fastest of all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method `map` builds a iterator, so the computes are made only when need it. So you need to force the computing, using a list for example

```
list(map(dct.update, inp))
print(dct)
```

---

**But** you shouldn't use either the list comprehension or the `map` operation that are here to produce values

You'd better keep your `for-loop` or a `dict-comprehension`

```
dct = {key:val for item in inp for key,val in item.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use map for this task?

If you want to solve it in one line you can just do:

```
dct={k:v for x in inp for k,v in x.items()}
```

Comment: or: `dict(x for xs in inp for x in xs.items())`

Answer (score 1):

With using Chain Map:

```
from collections import ChainMap

inp = [{1: 100}, {3: 200}, {8: 300}]
data = dict(ChainMap(*inp))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `reduce`, not `map`.  `map` creates a sequence by applying a function to each element of the given sequence, whereas `reduce` accumulates an object over the sequence.

```
from functools import reduce
inp = [{1:100}, {3:200}, {8:300}]
dct = {}
reduce(lambda d1, d2: (d1.update(d2) or d1), inp, dct)
```

```
{1: 100, 3: 200, 8: 300}
```

This `lambda` part may look tricky.  What this does is to create a function that updates a dict and returns the dictionary itself.  This is because `reduce` expects the accumulating function returns the updated object while `dict.update()` returns `None`.  Since `None` is interpreted as False, the `or` operator returns the second variable, which is the updated dictionary.

This `or` trick is credited to @kostya-goloveshko in this thread: [Why doesn't a python dict.update() return the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452995/why-doesnt-a-python-dict-update-return-the-object)

Comment: Thank you, indeed! I was interested in this kind of tooling, though the one line answer above is indeed more useful/practical for such a task.

Comment: Tricky, and very messy. I'm heavily against using NoneType falsity in such construct.

Comment: @goteguru it's also another example of using imperative code in a functional construct. Hence the messiness.