# Why does python's dict update() method return a None Type object?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to create a dictionary that can be used to apply a cipher to a letter. The dictionary maps every uppercase and lowercase letter to a character shifted down the alphabet by the input shift. The dictionary should have 52 keys of all the uppercase letters and all the lowercase letters only. This is a method built in a class.

Here is my code:

```
import string
def build_shift_dict(self, shift):
    '''
    shift (integer): the amount by which to shift every letter of the 
    alphabet. 0 <= shift < 26

    Returns: a dictionary mapping a letter (string) to 
             another letter (string). 
    '''
    dict1={}
    dict2={}
    alphabet_lowercase=string.ascii_lowercase
    alphabet_uppercase=string.ascii_uppercase
    for t in range(26):
        if t>=26-shift:
            dict1[alphabet_lowercase[t]]=alphabet_lowercase[abs((26-shift)-t)]
        else:
            dict1[alphabet_lowercase[t]]=alphabet_lowercase[t+shift]
    for t in range(26):
        if t>=26-shift:
            dict2[alphabet_uppercase[t]]=alphabet_uppercase[abs((26-shift)-t)]
        else:
            dict2[alphabet_uppercase[t]]=alphabet_uppercase[t+shift]
    dictionary=dict1.update(dict2)
    return dictionary
```

Although dict1 and dict2 are what I expected to get, the assignment to dictionary returns a None Type object. Is there anything wrong with the 'update' function?

Comment: The dictionary `.update()` method doesn't _return_ anything; it modifies the affected dict in-place.

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't a python dict.update() return the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452995/4518341)

Comment: FWIW, you can refactor this method so that you only need one dict. Something like `for a in string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase: ... d[a[t]] = a[...]`. I would also factor out the math to another variable to keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself): `i = t+shift if t < 26-shift else abs(26-shift-t); d[a[t]] = a[i]`

Answer (score 0):

To put [John Gordon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65745960/why-does-pythons-dict-update-method-return-a-none-type-object#comment116242839_65745960) into an answer with code, replace:

```py
dictionary=dict1.update(dict2)
return dictionary
```

with:

```py
dict1.update(dict2)
return dict1
```

Comment: Thank @JohnGordon, I just put his words into code.