# I am trying to input and update a dictionary without using a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I want a feature where i can input new values into a dictionary
to store and update so i can use it as part of code. Thanks

```
name_of_students = {'Sam':92,  'james':78, 'ray':67, 'jane':60, 'julie':89, 'mel':50} 
#add new variable into dict
new_students = {}
new_students = input("Enter the name of the student/score: ")
name_of_students = name_of_students.update(new_students)
print(name_of_students)
```

input **mark:90**

error: `raceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/sonter/Documents/CODE X/grading-program-/.py", line 10, in <module> name_of_students = name_of_students.update(new_students) ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Comment: `name_of_students.update([new_students.split(':')])` ?

Comment: @python_user *ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required* it doesnt work

Comment: @python_user got my brownie points ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#insert names of students



name_of_students = {'Sam':92,  'james':78, 'ray':67, 'jane':60, 'julie':89, 'mel':50} 
#add new variable into dict
new_students = {}
new_students = input("Enter the name of the student/score: ")
name_of_students = {new_students.split(
    ":")[0]: int(new_students.split(":")[1])}

print(name_of_students)
```

**Use index to split input and `int` function to declear
integer as input on the [1] index**

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
name_of_students = {'Sam':92,  'james':78, 'ray':67, 'jane':60, 'julie':89, 'mel':50} 
print(name_of_students)
#add new variable into dict
#name_of_students = {}
new_students = input("Enter the name of the student/score: ")
new_students = {new_students.split(':')[0] : int(new_students.split(':')[1])}
name_of_students = name_of_students.update(new_students) or name_of_students
print(name_of_students)
```

output:

```
{'Sam': 92, 'james': 78, 'ray': 67, 'jane': 60, 'julie': 89, 'mel': 50}
Enter the name of the student/score: mark:90
{'Sam': 92, 'james': 78, 'ray': 67, 'jane': 60, 'julie': 89, 'mel': 50, 'mark': 90}
```

from : [Why doesn't a python dict.update() return the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452995/why-doesnt-a-python-dict-update-return-the-object)