# Efficient way to copy pairs(key ,value) of dictionary in a list of dictionaries, and respect order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, memory-management

I want to copy a common dictionary

```
list_common_dictionary = [{'Gender':'M', 'Age':'25'}]
```

inside a data list dictionary \

```
list_data_dictionary = [{'name':'john','id':'1'},
                        {'name':'albert','id':'2'},
                        {'name':'jasper','id':'3'},
                        {'name':'guillaume','id':'4'}]
```

and get an output like :

```
output_dictionary = [{'Gender':'M', 'Age':'25','name':'john','id':'1'},
                     {'Gender':'M', 'Age':'25','name':'albert','id':'2'},
                     {'Gender':'M', 'Age':'25','name':'jasper','id':'3'},
                     {'Gender':'M', 'Age':'25','name':'guillaume','id':'4'}]
```

But respect the order of (fields of the common dictionary must be at the beginning of each output dictionary.
Regarding time cpu consumption, is deepcopy the most efficient way ?

Comment: That might depend on *how* you are using `deepcopy`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to merge dictionaries, `deepcopy` is unlikely to be relevant.

Comment: Is `list_common_dictionary` only ever going to contain one item? If so, why is that item wrapped in a list? If not, what is the desired behaviour if `len(list_common_dictionary) != 1`?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
result = [{**list_common_dictionary[0], **d} for d in list_data_dictionary]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'Gender': 'M', 'Age': '25', 'name': 'john', 'id': '1'}, {'Gender': 'M', 'Age': '25', 'name': 'albert', 'id': '2'}, {'Gender': 'M', 'Age': '25', 'name': 'jasper', 'id': '3'}, {'Gender': 'M', 'Age': '25', 'name': 'guillaume', 'id': '4'}]
```

Dictionaries keep insertion order in Python 3.6+ so this will guarantee that the keys from the common dictionary are the first ones.

Comment: merging with `dict(**d1, **d2)`? Would it be less performant?

Comment: I'm not sure but perhaps you could find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona

Comment: from the link: the `dict` is faster, but at the expense of readability

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`update in-place`** dictionary like below:

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56769083/1740577):

> For those coming late to the party, I had put some timing together (Py 3.7), showing that .update() based methods look a bit (~5%) faster when inputs are preserved and noticeably **(~30%) faster** when just **updating in-place.**

```
>>> for ldd in  list_data_dictionary:
...    ldd.update(*ist_common_dictionary)
    
>>> list_data_dictionary
[{'name': 'john', 'id': '1', 'Gender': 'M', 'Age': '25'},
 {'name': 'albert', 'id': '2', 'Gender': 'M', 'Age': '25'},
 {'name': 'jasper', 'id': '3', 'Gender': 'M', 'Age': '25'},
 {'name': 'guillaume', 'id': '4', 'Gender': 'M', 'Age': '25'}]
```